# emacs opening 2 windows in ubuntu - why?

Tags: emacs, ubuntu-14.04

I installed emacs ver 24 in ubuntu and when i launch it > emacs "file" - emacs opens with 2 windows split vertically.  One window has my "file" and the other window has the "Welcome to GNU Emacs .... " screen in it.

How do I stop it from opening the window with the "Welcome to GNU Emacs"?  Do i need to add something to my .emacs file?

Right now I have tried :

```
(setq inhibit-splash-screen-t)
(setq inhibit-startup-message-t)
(setq initial-scratch-message nil)
(setq delete-other-windows t)
```

None of which prevent the second window from opening with the emacs welcome.

Comment: I resolved this, needed to define the following in the .emacs file {setq-default inhibit-startup-message t)

Answer (score 0):

```
;; No emacs start-up message 
(setq inhibit-startup-message t)

;; Consider also to start a server
(server-start)
```

Such that your emacs instance is reused when opening multiple files